# Lie algebras are to Lie groups what Lie modules are to …?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to understand the relationship between Lie algebras, Lie groups, and Lie modules. I know that a Lie algebra is a vector space with a bilinear, antisymmetric, and Jacobi-satisfying bracket operation, and that a Lie group is a smooth manifold with a group structure that is compatible with the smooth structure. I also know that a Lie algebra can be seen as the tangent space at the identity of a Lie group.

A Lie algebra is defined by a field, and a Lie module is defined by a ring. I wonder if there is a similar notion of a Lie module for a Lie group, and if so, what is the name and the definition of it? Is there a correspondence between Lie modules and these objects, analogous to the correspondence between Lie algebras and Lie groups?

(My problems is to define an object which in its tangent is a Lie module (as defined below), as a Lie group is in its tangent a Lie algebra.)

****EDIT :****

I define a Lie module as :

A Lie Module is a module $\mathfrak {g}$ over some ring $R$ together with a binary operation  together with a binary operation $\displaystyle [\,\cdot \,,\cdot \,]:{\mathfrak {g}}\times {\mathfrak {g}}\to {\mathfrak {g}}$ called the Lie bracket satisfying bilinearity, alternativity, and the Jacobi identity.

Comment: It is not clear what your definition of a "Lie module" is: do you mean that a Lie module $L$ is an $R$-module for some commutative ring $R$ which carries an R-bilinear map $[-,-]\colon L \times L \to L$ that is alternating and satisfies the Jacobi identity?

Comment: Note that an $L$-module $M$ for a Lie algebra $L$ is an $U(L)$-module for the ring $U(L)$, the universal enveloping algebra. An $L$-module corresponds to a Lie group representation whose differential is the Lie algebra representation given by $M$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez What I mean is that a Lie module is a generalisation of a Lie algebra in the sens that it is not defined on a field, but on a ring.

Comment: Algebraic groups and group schemes over rings might be what you are looking for. The connection to Lie algebras over rings is probably not as strong as in the field case.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I have put the definition of a "Lie module"

Comment: @krm2233 I have put the definition of a "Lie module"

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have put the definition of a "Lie module"

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thank you very much. You could maybe make a full answer.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Group schemes are, in their tangent space, a module over a ring ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not the common definition of a Lie module. Usually, a Lie module (aka [Lie algebra representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_representation)) is defined as a module on which a Lie algebra acts (in a suitable way). A Lie algebra can be defined over any commutative ring (in fact, in every linear tensor category). This is all entirely analogous to associative algebras.

I think your question is rather what Lie groups over arbitrary commutative rings are. But Torsten already answered that in the comments. Lie groups are [group objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_object) in the category of smooth manifolds, so you essentially ask what manifolds over arbitrary commutative rings are. Well, one answer are (smooth) [schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(mathematics)). So the corresponding "Lie" objects are the (smooth) [group schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_scheme). The notion of [tangent spaces](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B28) is also defined for schemes.

Comment: Can we define a riemannian metric on a group scheme ?

Comment: Group schemes are, in their tangent space, a module over a ring ?